# Vectorizing a function in R

Tags: r, vectorization

It is supposed to make an n x n matrix with 2's along its diagonal and -1 on the first upper and lower diagonal.

```
   M <- function(n){
      m <- diag(x = 2, ncol = n, nrow = n)
      i <- 1
      for(i in 1:n-1){
        a <- i
        b <- i + 1
        m[a, b] <- -1
        m[b, a] <- -1
        i <- i + 1
      }
      return(m)
    }
```

it returns for example with n = 5, a 5 x 5 matrix

```
M(5)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2   -1    0    0    0
[2,]   -1    2   -1    0    0
[3,]    0   -1    2   -1    0
[4,]    0    0   -1    2   -1
[5,]    0    0    0   -1    2
```

I would like my function to return the same thing but without the for-loop.

Comment: How exactly do you want to vectorize it? Do you want it to work for a vector `n` rather than a single value? It's unclear what your desired result is here.

Comment: Perhaps `Vectorize(M)(5:6)`

Comment: I edited my original post to maybe help explain what I want. I don't want to use a for loop in my function.

Comment: BTW, your `1:n-1`. Do you intend for that to be `(1:n)-1` (starting at 0) or `1:(n-1)` (starting at 1)?

Comment: It is supposed to 1:(n-1), starting at 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you simply mean you don't want to use the for-loop. In that case, you could try:

```
M <- function(n){
  mat <- diag(2, n)
  mat[abs(row(mat) - col(mat)) == 1] <- -1
  mat
}

M(5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2   -1    0    0    0
[2,]   -1    2   -1    0    0
[3,]    0   -1    2   -1    0
[4,]    0    0   -1    2   -1
[5,]    0    0    0   -1    2
```

or even

```
M <- function(n){
  mat <- diag(2, n)
  u <- col(mat) == row(mat) + 1
  mat[u|t(u)] <- -1
  mat
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite as fancy as Onyambu's, but we can build the indexes directly:

```
M = function(n){
  m = diag(x = 2, ncol = n, nrow = n)
  x = cbind(2:n, 1:(n - 1))
  m[rbind(x, x[, 2:1])] = -1
  m
}

M(5)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2   -1    0    0    0
# [2,]   -1    2   -1    0    0
# [3,]    0   -1    2   -1    0
# [4,]    0    0   -1    2   -1
# [5,]    0    0    0   -1    2
```

Comment: I do perceive that this will be faster than my code if n is large. +1. Just curious. How do you manage to add `#` before each line of the output?

Comment: Ugh. I copy/paste the result from console to my editor window, then use a hotkey to comment it. It's not too bad, but I wish it was smoother.

Comment: Thanks. Thought it is a feature provided by stackoverflow

Comment: @Onyambu, check out [my "overflow" package](http://mrdwab.github.io/overflow-mrdwab/). `soread()` creates a `data.frame` from (most) copy-and-paste tables in your clipboard; `sodput()` copies an object to your clipboard ready to paste into a question; `soanswer()` copies the expression and your result to your clipboard, ready to paste into an answer.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 oooh, that sounds great! I've used `reprex` sometimes, but it's a little too strict for SO, better for Github issues.

Comment: @GregorThomas, try it out and let me know what you think of it. I like that it captures the output to your clipboard ready to paste (including padding with 4 spaces and so on for markdown). `soread` needs some updates now that the big players (data.table and dplyr) have options to print information about the column types.